# c9 access a mysql database from another project

Tags: php, mysql

I have one project running a database on a Cloud9 project.  I have created a mobile app which will need to connect to the database by POST to a PHP file which will then run the following code:

```
$servername = "myusername-projectname-somenumber";
$port = 3306;
$username = "form";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname, 3306);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

I got the servername by using this in the terminal:

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'hostname';
```

I am getting an error from the other project:

```
Connection failed: Unknown MySQL server host 'myusername-projectname-somenumber' (0)
```

***Note: I have replaced myusername-projectname-somenumber and dbname for posting this.  I did not forget to fill them out.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: try to use IP address of server as $servername

Comment: I tried to use the public ip address which didn't work. I think there might be some proxy settings blocking this.